# Unpermitted parameter: :file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working with a rails form, I have an Order model, and an Attachment model.

My orders_controller.rb includes this

```
        def order_params
         params.require(:order).permit(:file, attachments_attributes: [:id, :file, :_destroy], attachment: [:file], file: [])
        end
```

PATCH/PUT /orders/1 or /orders/1.json

```
        def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @order.update(order_params)

            ...

            if params[:order][:attachment] && params[:order][:attachment][:file]
              attachment = Attachment.new(file: params[:order][:attachment][:file])
              @order.attachments << attachment
            end

            @order.save
            format.html { redirect_to @order }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
        end
```

My order.rb

```
        has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
```

My attachment.rb

```
        belongs_to :order
        has_one_attached :file
```

My nested form is set like

```
        <%= form_with(model: @order, local: true, data: { turbo: false }) do |f| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment_fields| %>
                <%= attachment_fields.label :file, value: "Add documents" %>
                <%= attachment_fields.file_field :file, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 0, multiple: true  %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.button "My Button", type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

Error

```
        Unpermitted parameter: :file. Context: { controller: OrdersController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x000000010c115f00>, params: {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "order"=>{"attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"file"=>["", #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000010c27a238 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/p2/tt3rjy5s0m917fhkc4nkfnf80000gp/T/RackMultipart20230511-33878-nwzaw4.pdf>, @original_filename="CUESTIONARIO_KYC.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order[attachments_attributes][0][file][]\"; filename=\"CUESTIONARIO_KYC.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">], "id"=>"18"}}}, "button"=>"", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"229"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where your error is produced, but I would assume it's when you create the new `Attachment`; unless you need not to use the "curated" parameters for some reason, I would just use them in the rest of your code:

```rb
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.update(order_params)

      # ...
      if order_params[:attachment] && order_params[:attachment][:file]
        attachment = Attachment.new(file: order_params[:attachment][:file])
        @order.attachments << attachment
      end

      @order.save
  
      format.html { redirect_to @order }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're aware that the `:file` element is an array, and seems like you've tried to add the `:file` array element to your permit statement, but you've put it in the wrong place.

You need to have that inside the `attachments_attributes` section because that's what's being sent through from the nested `fields_for` form.

You can see in the error:

```
... {"attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"file"=>["", #<Action....] ...
```

...so you need to have in your permit statement:

```
attachments_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, file: []]
```